# Cobordism and Boundary Theorem (Guillemin-Pollack)

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, cobordism

> Prove that if $X$ and $Z$ are cobordant in $Y$, then for every closed
>   manifold $C$ in $Y$ with dimension complementary to $X$ and $Z$,
>   $I_2(X,C)=I_2(Z,C)$. [HINT: Let $f$ be the restriction to $W$ of the
>   projection map $Y\times I\to Y$, and use the Boundary Theorem.]
>
> **Boundary Theorem**. Suppose that $X$ is the boundary of some compact manifold $W$ and $g:X\to Y$ is a smooth map. If $g$ may be extended to
>   all of $W$, then $I_2(g,Z)=0$ for any closed submanifold $Z$ in $Y$ of
>   complementary dimension.

My progress:

Since $X$ and $Z$ are cobordant in $Y$, there is a compact manifold with boundary $W\subset Y\times I$ such that $\partial W=X\times \{0\}\cup Z\times \{1\}$. To apply the boundary theorem, I need to involve some boundary. Let $f$ be the restriction of the projection $Y\times I\to Y$ to $W$ and consider $\partial f=f\restriction_{\partial W}: \partial W\to Y$.  Now $\partial f$ satisfies the hypotheses of the boundary theorem, so $I_2(\partial f,C)=0$ for any closed submanifold $C$ in $Y$ of complementary dimension.

How do I conclude that  $I_2(X,C)=I_2(Z,C)$? I guess I need to use that  $\partial W=X\times \{0\}\cup Z\times \{1\}$ but I don't know how.

Comment: What is the definition of $I_2(X,C)$ for a submanifold $X$? Isn't it simply the intersection number of the inclusion $\iota:X\to Y$?

Comment: @cjackal, Yes it is.

Comment: Well, then what is $\partial f$? Isn't it just a disjoint union of the inclusions $X\to Y$ and $Z\to Y$, except that the orientation of one of the inclusions is reversed? Use the additivity of the intersection number to conclude what you desire.

Comment: @cjackal I'm not sure what you mean by union (and orientation) of maps (in this case inclusions), but I don't even see why $\partial f$ is an inclusion (strictly speaking, $X\times \{0\}$ isn't a subset of $Y$). Also, Guillemin and Pollack don't discuss the additivity of $I_2$ -- is this additivity supposed to be obvious?

Comment: Well, it is obvious that the identification of $X\times \left\{0\right\}$ with $X$ gives the viewpoint of $\partial f|_{X\times 0 }$ as an inclusion. Anyway, the intersection number "counts the (signed) intersection points", so the additivity should be obvious. And come to think of it, calling it a disjoint union is a bit nonsense; just try to exploit the additivity and my claim that one of the orientation in $\partial f$ is reversed.

Comment: @cjackal I'm still not sure what orientation you mean. The book doesn't discuss orientations at this point. In my understanding, the goal is to prove $I_2(\partial f, C)=I_2(X,C)+I_2(Z,C)$. The first term on the RHS is the number of points mod 2 in the set $j^{-1}(C)$ where $j$ is any map homotopic to the inclusion map $\iota: X\to Y$ and transverse to $C$. The second term on the RHS is defined similarly. The term on the LHS is the number of points mod 2 in the set $\rho^{-1}(C)$ where $\rho$ is any map homotopic to $\partial f$ and transverse to $C$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that your $I_2$ is the intersection number mod 2. Then we don't have orientation issues here, and it boils down to show the additivity that you have made explicit in your last comment. The homotopies of $X$ and $Z$ that make them transverse to $C$ define a homotopy of $\partial f$ and vice versa, simply because the domain of $\partial f$ is the disjoint union of $X$ and $Z$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @cjackal I'm afraid it's not... I assume you mean homotopies of the inclusion maps of $X$ and $Z$ to $Y$ (since being homotopic is a property of maps). I got some intuition about why this may be true, but I still don't have firm understanding to prove this formally. Even if I understood your statement about homotopy (which I, frankly, didn't), this wouldn't tell me why the result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know from the boundary theorem that $I_2(\partial f,C)=0$, it suffices to show that $I_2(X,C)+I_2(Z,C)=I_2(\partial f,C)$.

Now recall that the intersection number mod 2 is counting the number of intersection points of $\iota_X:X\to Y$ and $C$, after a proper homotopy that makes the intersection transverse. (Thus, $I_2(X,C)=I_2(\iota_X,C)$ by definition, and I will identify throughout this post.)

So let me assume that $H:X\times I\to Y$ is one such homotopy, so that $H|_{X\times 1}:X\to Y$ (up to the canonical identification $X\times \left\{1\right\}\cong X$ of course) is transverse to $C$. Similarly, one can find a homotopy $H':Z\times I \to Y$ from $\iota_Z$ to $H'|_{Z\times 1}:Z\to Y$ where the latter is transverse to $C$. Now observe that $\partial f:X\times \left\{0\right\}\sqcup Z\times \left\{1\right\}\to Y$ becomes $\partial f:X\sqcup Z\to Y$ after the canonical identifications. (Do I even need to elaborate on this?) And the homotopies $H$ and $H'$ give ries to a homotopy $H\sqcup H':(X\sqcup Z)\times I \to Y$ from $\partial f$ to $H|_{X\times 1}\cup H'|_{Z\times 1}:X\sqcup Z\to Y$. And now the transversality condition is local, so a disjoint union (coproduct if you like) of two maps transverse to $C$ is transverse to $C$. 
And the count of intersection points is clearly additive under this disjoint union as $(f\sqcup g)^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(y)\sqcup g^{-1}(y)$ for any maps $f,g$ and $y\in Y$. Thus, $I_2(\partial f,C)$, which is the count of the number of intersection points of $H|_{X\times 1}\cup H'|_{Z\times 1}:X\sqcup Z\to Y$ with $C$, coincides with the sum of the count of the number of intersection points of $H|_{X\times 1}:X\to Y$ and $H'|_{Z\times 1}:Z\to Y$, which is simply $I_2(X,C)+I_2(Z,C)$ Done.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it more clear.